# CSS/jQuery extractor Usage to extract content in td tag which doesn't have tag id

Tags: regex, jmeter

```html
<tr class="paxDetailRow" pax_seq="3" pax_sts="CUR">
    <td class="none">&nbsp;</td>
 <td class="borderFirst">3</td>
 <td>Master</td>
 <td class="tooltipParent" tooltipWidth="400">
          
 F
          
 </td>
 <td class="tooltipParent" tooltipWidth="400">
          
 Rowland
          
 </td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>8</td>
 <td class="price  borderLast">
 1723.84
 <div class="tooltipContent"></div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

From this I want to extract the value 8 **which is there inside td tag**

I tried some regex/css extractor but its not working out for me. As I'm new to usage of css/jQuery extractor I'm finding it difficult. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract it through:

> tr[class=paxDetailRow] > td:eq(6)

It will be much more efficient than using XPath.

[image]

Comment: You should ask another question on SO. Comments are not made for questions. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can get text inside a HTML tag using CSS selectors so I would suggest going for [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) instead.

The relevant XPath query will look like:

```
 //tr[@class='paxDetailRow']/td[7]/text()
```

Demo:

[image: XPath Extractor Demo]

References:

- [XPath 1.0 Language Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)
- [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

Comment: hi thanks for your reply..if there is one more  <tr class="paxDetailRow" pax_seq=**"n"** pax_sts="CUR"> where n could be anything. and i want to extract both .and use it further.  how can i use. ..can you please come up with some idea

Comment: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
im getting this error

Comment: The expression would be: `//tr[@class='paxDetailRow']/@pax_seq`. You can combine 2 XPath expressions via `|` operator like `//tr[@class='paxDetailRow']/@pax_seq | //tr[@class='paxDetailRow']/td[7]/text()`

Comment: this way also works.thanks.as i need to learn more about xpath this has become the platform.